# HttpDelete request with JSON payload in Android

Tags: android, json, http-delete

I need to call a web service to delete data, and I need to do it using HttpDelete. The service takes a JSON object as parameter.

I have done HttpPost before, using SetEntity, but this is not available with HttpDelete.

It's a call like http://url/DELETE/service and something like `{ id: "xxxxxxx", id2: 11 }` as parameter.

I can't find any good info on this. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [HttpDelete with body](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3773338/842697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send a body in a HTTP DELETE request.

If you need to do that, there is probably something wrong with your REST design.

Why not `http://url/srvice/xxxxxx/11` instead of `http://url/DELETE/service` with a body ?

Answer (score 1):

[RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) doesn't specify anything about a entity on an HTTP DELETE request.  I would say your best bet is to pass the values you need in the path of your request.

> http: //url/DELETE/service/xxxxxx/11

Answer (score 0):

The id is most likely passed in the url OR possibly could be passed in a header value.   Here's an example:

```
HttpDelete httpdelete = new HttpDelete(targetURL);                              
httpdelete.setHeader("id",id);  // If not in the url, this could be where the id is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are use cases when this would be awesome. One I'm running into now is a need for a "bulk delete". Basically, for efficiency reasons, deleting one entry at a time is way slower than it would be to delete multiple entries at once. I'm forced to use POST and be un-RESTful. In my opinion, this is a design flaw in REST, or at least a design limitation.