# How to send PUT, DELETE HTTP request in HttpURLConnection in JAVA

Tags: java, http, rest, httpurlconnection

I have Restful WebServices, and i send POST and GET HTTP request, how to send PUT and DELTE request HTTP in httpURLConection with JAVA.

Comment: As an alternative for native usage of HttpURLConnection you can use a tiny library called [DavidWebb](https://github.com/hgoebl/DavidWebb). There you can find a list of similar libraries. Using HttpURLConnection natively is cumbersome and error prone.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

PUT

```
URL url = null;
try {
   url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/putservice");
} catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
try {
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.write("hello");
} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}  finally {
    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
        try {
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (httpsURLConnection != null) {
        httpsURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

DELETE

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/deleteservice");
} catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
try {
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
    System.out.println(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} finally {         
    if (httpURLConnection != null) {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to call htpURLConnection.connect()? What is this function for?

Answer (score 5):

If I use the DELETE request from @BartekM, it get this exception:

```
 java.net.ProtocolException: DELETE does not support writing
```

To fix it, I just remove this instruction:

```
 // httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

source: [Sending HTTP DELETE request in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338615/sending-http-delete-request-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

you can override

```
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest req,
                      HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException;
```

> Performs the HTTP PUT operation; the default implementation reports an
>   HTTP BAD_REQUEST error. The PUT operation is analogous to sending a
>   file via FTP. Servlet writers who override this method must respect
>   any Content-* headers sent with the request. (These headers include
>   content-length, content-type, content-transfer-encoding,
>   content-encoding, content-base, content-language, content-location,
>   content-MD5, and content-range.) If the subclass cannot honor a
>   content header, then it must issue an error response (501) and discard
>   the request. For more information, see the HTTP 1.1 RFC.
>
> This method does not need to be either "safe" or "idempotent".
>   Operations requested through PUT can have side effects for which the
>   user can be held accountable. Although not required, servlet writers
>   who override this method may wish to save a copy of the affected URI
>   in temporary storage.

and

```
 protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req,
                         HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
```

> Performs the HTTP DELETE operation; the default implementation reports
>   an HTTP BAD_REQUEST error. The DELETE operation allows a client to
>   request a URI to be removed from the server. This method does not need
>   to be either "safe" or "idempotent". Operations requested through
>   DELETE can have side-effects for which users may be held accountable.
>   Although not required, servlet writers who subclass this method may
>   wish to save a copy of the affected URI in temporary storage.

Comment: Those are Servlet API methods but the OP is asking about an HTTP client I think

Comment: Maybe, but I understood that he already has implemented a servlet that manages doGet and doPut and wants to know how to implement the other two operations

Comment: if, as I have the getter and postT, I need to implement delete, and put methods, however do not come because tenngo one input parameter can help me? - @MatthewGilliard