# Perform HTTP DELETE with api address and json data using java

Tags: java, android, http-delete

I know that to send a POST request to the web I can use this syntax:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(api_address);
    String response = null;
    int status_code = -1;

    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json_data, HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("application/json");

     // Set entity
      post.setEntity(se);
```

However, the setEntity methos does not exist for DELETE. So what are the alternatives to send a DELETE with data?

I gave a look to this: [HttpDelete with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body)

but I didnt understand it really... I'm just a beginner!

Comment: i really don't think delete should have a body. => what data do you want to pass ?

Comment: also, what don't you understand about HttpDeleteWithBody ?

Comment: an object, that is a user I want to delete from a list

Comment: I'm trying do implement it right now as @fiddler told me ;) i don't understand pretty well how HttpDeleteWithbody works

Comment: the object you want to delete should be identified by the query in the uri, not by the body of your delete request

Comment: what should i write in the uri?

Comment: probably an element identifying your element to delete. you typically will be requesting a delete to an url you could request a get on.

Comment: ok, I have the api address and the element that identifies my element, how can I add the element to the uri?

Comment: Maybe something like this? www.abcd.com/example?id=elementtoidentify

Comment: it should be the same url as for a GET, so yes, this could be it

Answer (score 4):

You can use the solution provided in [HttpDelete with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body) like this:

```
HttpDeleteWithBody delete = new HttpDeleteWithBody(api_address);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json_data, HTTP.UTF_8);
se.setContentType("application/json");

delete.setEntity(se);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
But the code listed in 
[HttpDelete with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body)

is using annotation library so removed below portion if you do not wanted to include annotation jars else it is ok.

Import: import org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe;

Annotation above the class:@NotThreadSafe

and place the class in the application and use it according to "fiddler's" comment.

I am sure you can have result.As i am getting success.