# HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase and HttpOptions

Tags: java, httpclient

I need to be able to set an entity on an OPTIONS call but looks like HttpClient does not support it.  HttpPost and HttpPut extend from HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase, while HttpOptions does not.

Anyone know the reason for this, or if there is a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this, here is how did this for HttpClient.

```
@Autowired
HttpClient httpClient;

public HttpResponse execute(String url, String json, String accessToken) {
    HttpOptionsWithBody httpOptionsWithBody = new HttpOptionsWithBody(url);
    httpOptionsWithBody.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
    return httpClient.execute(httpOptionsWithBody);
}

private static class HttpOptionsWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {

    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "OPTIONS";

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }

    public HttpOptionsWithBody(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }
}
```

I got the idea on how to do this from [HttpDelete with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body/3820549#3820549)

Answer (score 0):

The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) states

> If the OPTIONS request includes an entity-body (as indicated by the
>   presence of Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding), then the media type
>   MUST be indicated by a Content-Type field. **Although this specification
>   does not define any use for such a body, future extensions to HTTP
>   might use the OPTIONS body to make more detailed queries on the
>   server.** A server that does not support such an extension MAY discard
>   the request body.

The Apache Http Client team probably decided that there was no use case that would warrant a request body in a OPTIONS request.

Comment: There is at least one public facing API out there that has a body in the OPTIONS call.  I'm trying to figure out how to work around this.  Found one solution that works if we were just using HttpClient, but we have jersey on top of that.