# HttpDelete a parameter with setEntity on android?

Tags: java, android, http-delete

I try to delete a parameter with this :

```
private class SendfeedbackDeleteStudio extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "DeleteStudio";
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String token= extras.getString("TOKEN");
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String venid = params[0];
        Utils.log("venid: " + venid);
        final String url_delete_studio = Constant.URI_BASE_FAVOURITE;
        String contentType;
        contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // do above Server call here
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vendor_id", venid));
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(url_delete_studio);
            httpDelete.setHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
            httpDelete.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            httpDelete.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpDelete.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
            httpDelete.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpDelete);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                // EntityUtils to get the reponse content
                String content =  EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                Utils.log("daftar content: " + content);
                JSONObject hasiljson = new JSONObject(content);
                Utils.log("hasiljson object: " + hasiljson);
                String success = hasiljson.getString("success");
                Utils.log("success: " + success);
            }
            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.format("Error during delete: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
        return "processing";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message
        clickFavourites();
    }
}
```

but it get red on httpDelete.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));, it seems it cannot recognize the parameter that I sent to delete. How to delete venid parameter?

Comment: Delete parameter from where?

Comment: from database (mysql)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP DELETE acts like GET variant so it won't take any inputs.

If you are looking to provide a delete with a body, you might want to consider using a POST to a location that accepts a body.

or you can use this

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
import java.net.URI;
import org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe;

@NotThreadSafe
class HttpDeleteWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "DELETE";
    public String getMethod() { return METHOD_NAME; }

    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }
    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final URI uri) {
        super();
        setURI(uri);
    }
    public HttpDeleteWithBody() { super(); }
}
```

which is referred from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body)

Comment: how to use that with my url and parameter?

Comment: or it is better use GET, and in api's SQL use DELETE command?

Comment: @carijawaban Do you have access to the api's code? if yes I suggest you to change the code to receive POST instead DELETE, and then put the entity into HTTP POST and then use SQL DELETE in your API code

Comment: i do not have access to api, but my friend has access, I will ask if he want to change it.